# After Shopware installation, Problems with terminal

Tags: php, shopware

i have installed last version of Shopware (5.4.2) in local. Following the instructions, all works correctly; and in particular I can login in the backend side (so, the database credentials are correct). But if I try to use the terminal (for example, to see the plugin list) I see the attach error message. Why? How can I solve the problem?

The command is bin/console sw:plugin:list

Thank you very much,

Federico

[image]

Comment: To me this looks like a Mac issue. Could you please execute `which php` and post the output here? My suspicion is that it executes another php install.

Answer (score 0):

Change the MySQL host in your config.php to 127.0.0.1